# Pandas Axis Order Inconsistency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, panel

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame, Panel, Panel4D

s=Series({'A1':1,'B1':2})
df=DataFrame({'A2':s,'B2':s})
p=Panel({'A3':df,'B3':df})
p4=Panel4D({'A4':p,'B4':p})

print(s.axes)
print(df.axes)
print(p.axes)
print(p4.axes)
```

Run the above, and it's pretty obvious that other than the second level (DataFrame), each other level adds an additional layer of "index" or "axis" on top in sequence. This gives me an extremely dirty feeling. It's extremely unpure. Is this by design? Is there an option, or an argument I can provide to the constructor that can consistently fix this?

Comment: you might find this discussion interesting:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pydata/3A-ZTryjm2c